# How to turn flat list into hierarchical one using ramda?

Tags: javascript, ramda.js

Like in question. I would like to turn the following list into hierarchical list with children fields. 'parentId' can stay. I just removed it for clarity. The goal is to use ramda with its immutable behavior.

```
const x = [
  {
    id: 1,
    parentId: null,
    name: 'Top 1'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    parentId: 1,
    name: 'Middle'
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    parentId: 2,
    name: 'Leaf'
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    parentId: null,
    name: 'Top 2'
  },
];
```

into this one:

```
const result = [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Top 1',
        children: [
            {
                id: 2,
                name: 'Middle',
                children: [
                    {
                        id: 3,
                        name: 'Leaf',
                        children: []
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        name: 'Top 2',
        children: []
    }
];
```

Comment: is the data sorted? have you tried anything? what does not work?

Comment: I don't know what Ramda is, but I would recommend the following: iterate over the original array, looking for anything with a null parentId, and put them as the base elements in a new array, marking them as 'handled' or something. Then iterate over those new elements, looking for all items in the original array with a 'parentId' of their id, and add it to their children. Then do the same thing for their children, recursively, and so on.

Comment: I know how to implement it with mutable data structures, it is really trivial. I don't know how to specifically implement it using ramda and immutable data structures.

Comment: Ramda treats objects/arrays as immtuable by always returning a new version instead of mutating the original one. objects/arrays are still normal, mutable data types, though. Immutable data types use structural sharing to avoid deep cloning in most cases. You have to use a lib like immutable.js to do this in JS. However, Immutable.js objects are not interoperable with vanilla JS objects. That is you need helpers to do the plumbing with Ramda. A brief search didn't yield any currently maintained repo.

Comment: @ftor, I haven't written I need real immutability, but immutable behavior of ramda which I know. I know how ramda works, There is no need to exaplain it again and again in comments here. Also, there is no need for comments about implementations without ramda. We have a project that follows "point free" programming using ramda and this is the first problem we met in last few months. I'm only looking for solutions in Ramda. If someone don't know ramda its better to not waste our times to write comments in this thread.

Comment: @ftor Why have you removed a tag, when you said in the first sentence that ramda treats objects as immutable?

Comment: @KrzysztofPniak perhaps you could provide your original mutative implementation and we can look at making it more fp?

Answer (score 1):

In a pure Ramda / point-free / functional style, I would do the following:

```
const overChildren = over(lensProp('children'))
const findChildren = completeList => parent => filter(child => child.parentId === parent.id, completeList)

const assocChildren = completeList => map(pipe(
  parent => assoc('children', findChildren(completeList)(parent), parent),
  parent => overChildren(assocChildren(completeList), parent)
))

const removeParentIds = map(pipe(
  dissoc('parentId'),
  overChildren(x => removeParentIds(x))
))

const isTop = compose(isNil, prop('parentId'))
const keepOnlyTop = filter(isTop)

const hierarchize = completeList => pipe(
  assocChildren(completeList),
  keepOnlyTop,
  removeParentIds
)(completeList)

hierarchize(list)
```

[Try it here](https://ramdajs.com/repl/#?const%20list%20%3D%20%5B%0A%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20id%3A%201%2C%0A%20%20%20%20parentId%3A%20null%2C%0A%20%20%20%20name%3A%20%27Top%201%27%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20id%3A%202%2C%0A%20%20%20%20parentId%3A%201%2C%0A%20%20%20%20name%3A%20%27Middle%27%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20id%3A%203%2C%0A%20%20%20%20parentId%3A%202%2C%0A%20%20%20%20name%3A%20%27Leaf%27%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20id%3A%204%2C%0A%20%20%20%20parentId%3A%20null%2C%0A%20%20%20%20name%3A%20%27Top%202%27%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0A%5D%3B%0A%0Aconst%20overChildren%20%3D%20over%28lensProp%28%27children%27%29%29%0Aconst%20findChildren%20%3D%20completeList%20%3D%3E%20parent%20%3D%3E%20filter%28child%20%3D%3E%20child.parentId%20%3D%3D%3D%20parent.id%2C%20completeList%29%0A%0Aconst%20assocChildren%20%3D%20completeList%20%3D%3E%20map%28pipe%28%0A%20%20parent%20%3D%3E%20assoc%28%27children%27%2C%20findChildren%28completeList%29%28parent%29%2C%20parent%29%2C%0A%20%20parent%20%3D%3E%20overChildren%28assocChildren%28completeList%29%2C%20parent%29%0A%29%29%0A%0Aconst%20removeParentIds%20%3D%20map%28pipe%28%0A%20%20dissoc%28%27parentId%27%29%2C%0A%20%20overChildren%28x%20%3D%3E%20removeParentIds%28x%29%29%0A%29%29%0A%0Aconst%20isTop%20%3D%20compose%28isNil%2C%20prop%28%27parentId%27%29%29%0Aconst%20keepOnlyTop%20%3D%20filter%28isTop%29%0A%0Aconst%20hierarchize%20%3D%20completeList%20%3D%3E%20pipe%28%0A%20%20assocChildren%28completeList%29%2C%0A%20%20keepOnlyTop%2C%0A%20%20removeParentIds%0A%29%28completeList%29%0A%0Ahierarchize%28list%29%0A%0A%2F%2A%20const%20result%20%3D%20%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20id%3A%201%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20name%3A%20%27Top%201%27%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20children%3A%20%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20id%3A%202%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20name%3A%20%27Middle%27%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20children%3A%20%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20id%3A%203%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20name%3A%20%27Leaf%27%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20children%3A%20%5B%5D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20id%3A%204%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20name%3A%20%27Top%202%27%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20children%3A%20%5B%5D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%5D%3B%20%2A%2F)

Note: I've focused on the readability and maintainability, not on performance.

Answer (score 0):

As I answered in [Gitter](https://gitter.im/ramda/ramda?at=59dba84501110b7231954fdc), this seems to do it:

```
const makeTree = items => {
  const hierarchy = reduce(
    (index, item) => item.parentId in index 
      ? assoc(item.id, [], assoc(item.parentId, append(item.id, index[item.parentId]), index))
      : assoc(item.id, [], index)
    , {}, 
    items
  ) //=> E.g. {"1":[2],"2":[3],"3":[],"4":[]} 
  const index = map(head, groupBy(prop('id'), items)) //=> E.g. {"!": <item1>, "2": <item2>, ...}
  const makeNode = id => dissoc('parentId', assoc('children',  map(makeNode, hierarchy[id]), index[id]))

  return map(makeNode, pluck('id', filter(item => item.parentId == null, items)))
}
```

It does involve several passes through the data, and the use of `groupBy` here seems a bit hacky, but I think it's reasonable.

Also those nested `assoc`s aren't pretty. I might refactor into `compose`/`pipe`.

You can see this in action on the **[Ramda REPL](http://ramdajs.com/repl/#?const%20x%20%3D%20%5B%0A%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20id%3A%201%2C%0A%20%20%20%20parentId%3A%20null%2C%0A%20%20%20%20name%3A%20%27Top%201%27%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20id%3A%202%2C%0A%20%20%20%20parentId%3A%201%2C%0A%20%20%20%20name%3A%20%27Middle%27%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20id%3A%203%2C%0A%20%20%20%20parentId%3A%202%2C%0A%20%20%20%20name%3A%20%27Leaf%27%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20id%3A%204%2C%0A%20%20%20%20parentId%3A%20null%2C%0A%20%20%20%20name%3A%20%27Top%202%27%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0A%5D%3B%0A%0Aconst%20makeTree%20%3D%20items%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20const%20hierarchy%20%3D%20reduce%28%0A%20%20%20%20%28index%2C%20item%29%20%3D%3E%20item.parentId%20in%20index%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3F%20assoc%28item.id%2C%20%5B%5D%2C%20assoc%28item.parentId%2C%20append%28item.id%2C%20index%5Bitem.parentId%5D%29%2C%20index%29%29%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3A%20assoc%28item.id%2C%20%5B%5D%2C%20index%29%0A%20%20%20%20%2C%20%7B%7D%2C%20%0A%20%20%20%20items%0A%20%20%29%20%2F%2F%3D%3E%20E.g.%20%7B%221%22%3A%5B2%5D%2C%222%22%3A%5B3%5D%2C%223%22%3A%5B%5D%2C%224%22%3A%5B%5D%7D%20%0A%20%20const%20index%20%3D%20map%28head%2C%20groupBy%28prop%28%27id%27%29%2C%20items%29%29%20%2F%2F%3D%3E%20E.g.%20%7B%22%21%22%3A%20%3Citem1%3E%2C%20%222%22%3A%20%3Citem2%3E%2C%20...%7D%0A%20%20const%20makeNode%20%3D%20id%20%3D%3E%20dissoc%28%27parentId%27%2C%20assoc%28%27children%27%2C%20%20map%28makeNode%2C%20hierarchy%5Bid%5D%29%2C%20index%5Bid%5D%29%29%0A%20%0A%20%20return%20map%28makeNode%2C%20pluck%28%27id%27%2C%20filter%28item%20%3D%3E%20item.parentId%20%3D%3D%20null%2C%20items%29%29%29%0A%7D%0A%0AmakeTree%28x%29%0A)**.